# How to apply markov process in a directed acyclic graph?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, linear-transformations, markov-chains, markov-process

Is it possible to apply the Markov process on a DAG and get steady-state vector? Or I must need to convert it to a Markov chain?

Comment: Your question is kind of broad; do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: Let I have a directed graph with node A, B, C and  the edges are B->A,C->A, C->B and I know the transition probability of the edges. But if I now calculate the steady-state vector then all the value will be concentrated on A.  Is there any other way to calculate the steady-state vector? or I need to add node and edges to this graph to make it stochastic, irreducible and aperiodic? Though it will change the original structure. @Math1000

Comment: If your specific problem is modeled by that DAG, and there is no way out of state $A$, then that is a perfectly valid Markov Chain and its steady state is $p_A=1, p_B=p_C=0$.  There is nothing wrong with that.